# Creating a stored function in SQL Server to generate id from sequence

Tags: sql-server

I have a created sequence in SQL Server like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.cust_acc_seq
    START WITH 1771  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;  
GO
```

I'm trying to create a stored function to return next value from the sequence, below is the code for the same.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetSeq_Cust_Acc()
RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Work VARCHAR(250)
    SET @Work = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.cust_add_seq
    RETURN @work
END
```

But while executing this I'm getting this error:

> NEXT VALUE FOR function is not allowed in check constraints, default objects, computed columns, views, user-defined functions, user-defined aggregates, user-defined table types, sub-queries, common table expressions, or derived tables.

Please let me know if I'm missing something while defining the stored function.

Comment: Well... it's not allowed (because functions can't affect data). You _could_ put it in a stored procedure instead. But since it doesn't really do much, why even out it in a function / stored procedure at all??

Comment: Also note your function is doing implicit casting (INT to VARCHAR) which is bad practice.

Comment: @Rakesh are you realy sure this is SQL? Sequence is for PLSQL

Comment: So which part of **NEXT VALUE FOR function is not allowed in ..... user-defined functions** do you *not* understand? The error clearly says: you're **not allowed** to use `NEXT VALUE FOR` in a function. So you just cannot do this - you'll need to think of another way to do this (like using a default constraint on the column, or a trigger, or something else)